# ALB to map multiple context path on one common port (tomcat)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently, we have tomcat based deployments and one Apache server to manage multiple context path on the same port (v-host configuration)

For example,

**ProxyPassMatch /test(.) http://127.0.0.1:7077/test$1**

**ProxyPassMatch /test2(.) http://127.0.0.1:7077/test2$1**

and so on

Now we are shifting towards ALB of AWS and we want to map all those context paths in ALB as present in Apache configuration file.

We created **ALB --> Listener on 80 Port --> Target created with a Necessary Instance with port 7077 --> health check is passed**

Listener rule is,

**Context path /test --> Forward to Target Group of 7077 port**

**Context path /test2 --> Forward to Target Group of 7077 port**

But while testing it is showing 502 Bad Gateway when we shut down Apache and to test ALB

Any Solutions?